# ActionChains in for loop

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to download files from a website using Selenium with Python. After using `find_elements_by()`, I am getting a list of 2 elements. I tried to loop over them in order to download the files present in those elements. I am getting only 1 file downloaded even though when I print the elements, I am getting both the elements.

Can someone please suggest something?

The following is my code:

```
action = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
x = driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('y')
for i in x:
    action.move_to_element(i).click(i).perform()
    print(i)
```